# Why would partial derivatives not commute inside an axionic cosmic string?

Tags: calculus, axion, cosmic-string

In this [1985 paper by Callan and Harvey](http://theory.uchicago.edu/%7Eharvey/pdf_files/callan_harvey_1984.pdf#page=4), Eq. $11$ seems to claim that in the presence of an infinitely extended string-like topological defect, partial derivatives do not commute on the string:

$$
[\partial_x, \partial_y]\, \theta = 2\pi \delta(x)\delta(y)\,. \tag{11}
$$

This is apparently "because of the topology of the axion string." I do not quite follow. Can someone please explain the reasoning to me in a bit more detail? In other words, I would like a more explicit derivation of the above equation. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integral
$$
I_\gamma=\oint_\gamma d\theta= \oint (\partial_x\theta dx +\partial_y \theta dy)= \oint\nabla \theta  \cdot d{\bf r}
$$
is $2\pi$ if the loop $\gamma$ encloses the origin and  zero if it does not. Now use Stokes' theorem
$$ 
I_\gamma = \int_\Omega \nabla\times (\nabla\theta) d^2r , \quad \partial \Omega=\gamma.
$$
Interpreting  the fact that   $I_\gamma$ is $2\pi$ or zero depending on whether the origin lies  within $\Omega$  as a statement about distributions, we read off that  $\nabla\times (\nabla \theta)= 2\pi \delta^2(x,y)$.
In components this is $\partial_x \partial_y \theta - \partial_y\partial_x \theta = 2\pi  \delta^2(x,y)$.